# Counting SparQL subjects with certain properties without Nestation

Tags: sparql

I have a SparQL query which first gets me the subjects with one of two predicates.
Then, I group them by a third predicate (that can also be blank) and count the grouped contained subjects.

How (if possible) can I do this without nestation?

My Query currently looks like this:

```
SELECT ?d (COUNT(?a) AS ?aCount)
    WHERE{
        SELECT ?d ?a
            WHERE {
                    ?a ?b ?c
                    FILTER (?b=:x||?b=:y)
                    OPTIONAL {?a :z ?d}
        }
    GROUP BY ?a ?d
    }
GROUP BY ?d
```

This works, as far as I know, but is with nestation.

Thanks!

Comment: what is the point of `?pred=:y` in the filter? There is no `?pred`  - I assume you mean a more readable `FILTER(?b IN (:x, :y))` or even better `VALUES ?b {:x :y}`

Comment: what is the purpose of the subquery? why the group by there? All the subquery currently generates are distinct tuples `?d ?a` - a plain `DISTINCT would return the same.

Comment: that said, why the subquery at all? what does not work with `SELECT ?d (COUNT(?a) AS ?aCount) {VALUES ?b {:x :y} ?a ?b ?c . OPTIONAL {?a :z ?d}} GROUP BY ?d` ?

Comment: regarding 1: i missed something while generalizing, the IN filter is probably more readable, yeah. Edited that.

Comment: Regarding why the subquery: if I do what you offered (i just pasted it and replaced the :x,:y,:z placeholders), the query returns a whole lot more results. 
I had something like that in place, but assumed it was wrong.

Your code also doesn't give me the proper result, but if I add a distinct (I wanna count distinct subjects, not their qualifying edges) to count, it works! Thx!

I kind of got into subqueries since they are easy to formulate and was thinking in subqueries.